# Using dynamic methods

Tags: php

Why does my dynamic method `usersMethod` not return any result?
The page is always empty.

```
<?php
class SampleClass
{
    public function __call($name, $args)
    {
        $m = $this->methods();

        eval($m['usersMethod']);
    }

    public function methods()
    {
        $methods = array(
            'usersMethod'=>'$a=2; return $a;', 
            'membersMethod'=>'$a=1; return $a;'
        );

        return $methods;
    }
}
$sample = new SampleClass();
echo $sample->usersMethod();
?>
```

Comment: You should really change `__call()` to use the name and args passed in instead of hard-coding it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return the value of [`eval`](http://php.net/eval):

```
return eval($m['usersMethod']);
```

(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167957/php-created-method-dynamically/6167983#6167983))

Answer (score 2):

You have an `return` statement in the code snippets that are to be used as "functions". But this return only sends the value over the eval(). You need to return the eval result as well:

```
 return eval($m['usersMethod']);
```

Only then will the internal $a be returned via the __call() method invocation.